# DataTables SQL Server UI Output

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, datatables, server-side

I have the following PHP code that connects to MS SQL SERVER and shows the data.

**Can you show me by a simple example on how to convert the output to DataTables?**

```
<?php
include("conn.php");

$sql = "SELECT * from contact";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

while($value=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
{ 
  echo "$value[ID]", " ... $value[Name]", ", $value[Address]", "<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is build an HTML table from your array result (this assumes an associative array):

```php
<?php
    echo '<table id="MainTable">';

    echo '<thead>';
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach (array_keys($results[0]) as $key) {
        echo "<th>$key</th>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</thead>';

    echo '<tbody>';
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach (array_keys($row) as $key) {
            echo '<td>$row[$key]</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</tbody>';
?>
```

And then activate `DataTable` on it with javascript either linked in a separate file or in the `<head>` element:

```
$(function () {
    $('#MainTable').DataTable();
}
```

See [DataTables Documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html)

Comment: PHP Warning:  array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\getWebsite.php on line 23
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\getWebsite.php on line 23
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\getWebsite.php on line 30

Comment: Is your `$result` null? Check your SQL statement and verify you're actually getting data